# 0.5 Second Button Pressed, Play half of animation and sound? (edited, better conveyed))

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

In my app you press a button and it plays an animation frame 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

However what I want is basically pressing the button for 0.2 seconds plays frames 1,2,3 but pressing it for 0.5 seconds plays frames 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc...The more frames are played the longer you hold the button. I want this with the sound that plays when you press the same button i.e.play first 0.2 seconds of the sound with 0.2 seconds of the button pressed etc..

I am really struggling to get this to work on find a good tutorial because I am just a beginner. So please help but remember to explain with as much instruction as possible. Here is my code:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {

}
- (IBAction)Button {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);

}




-(IBAction)startanimating{
    animatedimage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_00.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_20.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_30.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_35.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_45.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_50.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_50.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_45.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_45.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_45.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_40.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_35.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_35.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_35.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_30.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_30.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_30.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_25.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_20.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_20.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_20.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_15.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_10.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_05.png"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"frames_00.png"],nil];




    [animatedimage setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    animatedimage.animationDuration = 0.7;
    [animatedimage startAnimating];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AVTREV" ofType:@"mp3"]];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);



    {


    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have also heard I should use CALayers and CAanimation for this, would this be better? if so please provide help on how I can use CA and how to implement the button duration thing. Thank you I will really appreciate the help! :D

(This is not a repost, sorry for the confusion, This post is more focused on the animation and better articulated.

Answer (score 0):

First declare a class property to hold your time.

Then:

```
UIButton * myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 20.0);
[myButton setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userEndsTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userStartsTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void)userStartsTap:(id)sender {
// start time measurement
}

- (void)userEndsTap:(id)sender {
// stop time measurement, get duration and execute code according to time passed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I have no real idea where to put this line of code and what to replace exactly? If you don't mind could you please provide me with some more guidance. Thanks!

Comment: The UIButton code can be placed in the viewDidLoad. It's a way of programmatically creating a button. Alternately you can skip the button creation code and use the interface builder to connect the userStarts and userEnds to the same button. If you do that, don't forget to change void to IBAction.